# Shortcut for Pan View in Edit Mode

Tags: interface, customization, shortcut

I used the Maya hotkey preset and then I changed View Move to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> but this only works in Object Mode, in Edit Mode this shortcut does nothing except select.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @pycoder I mean where can I find the hotkeys that are relevant in Edit Mode context?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all of the current hotkeys for your Blender installation in File > User Preferences > Input.

Then you can search for what you are looking for; use "name" to search based on the name of the operator, use "key-binding" to search based on the hotkey itself.

[image: Demo]

Here is a specific use example:

[image]

Comment: I'm asking a specific question, Under `3D View / 3D View (Global)` change `Move View`.
 Test your change in the viewport, then select an object, enter into Edit Mode by hitting `TAB` and see if the hotkey is still applicable.

Comment: @JonneyShih Please look at my edit. I switched it to use the LMB instead of the MMB, and it works just fine in and out of edit mode. You should search for the hotkey that you are trying to add before you add a new one. You can do this easily with the ["is key free" add-on](https://github.com/Antonioya/blender).